# What variety is this chilli plant?

Tags: chili

I got it in a 'grow your own chilli in a tin can' but it didn't have a variety.[image][image]

Comment: Looks like a jalapeño

Comment: Thanks for the reply, photos of jalapenos look smoother though ?

Comment: Just from this photo it impossible to discover the variety. There are so many different varieties. Flowers and the form of plant could help. But never just the fruit. If it growth from seed (not specially prepared), probably it has no variety.

Comment: Nature is unpredictable and complex.

Comment: Not an answer, but the plant appears to be a Capsiscum annuum plant, the species that gives us everything from bell peppers to jalapenos to cayenne. When the fruit finish growing it might be possible to tell.

Comment: Added a new photo